# Use of map within the scope of cond

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I've shamelessly lifted almost all of this code from an example blogpost I had found (but now can't seem to retrieve) that demonstrated using Java's socket implementation to maintain a simple IRC connection.

While playing around a bit with the example I ran into a problem where I wanted to join a series of channels. My first thought was to store a vector of channels on the server var and then destructure it when a pattern was matched. However this so far as not worked. If I change the map to a bare invocation of the write function things work fine. However mapping the write function doesn't seem to work and I'm at a loss as to why. Interestingly enough if I copy and paste the map invocation into the repl running an active connection it works... So is this because this is happening in the scope of cond? Is the ref possibly to blame? I'm just breaking into Clojure so I'm still very much trying to figure things out.

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
  (ns irc
    (:import (java.net Socket)
            (java.io PrintWriter InputStreamReader BufferedReader)))

  (def server {:server "irc.example.net"
               :port 6667
               :channels ["#a" "#b"]})
  (def client {:realname "Lambda Bot" :nick "lambdabot"})

  (declare conn-handler)


  (defn in [a b]
    (re-find (re-pattern a) b))


  (defn startswith [a b]
    (in (str "^" a) b))


  (defn connect [server]
    (let [socket (Socket. (:server server) (:port server))
          in (BufferedReader. (InputStreamReader. (.getInputStream socket)))
          out (PrintWriter. (.getOutputStream socket))
          conn (ref {:in in :out out})]
      (doto (Thread. #(conn-handler conn server)) (.start))
      conn))


  (defn write [conn msg]
    (println msg)
    (doto (:out @conn)
      (.println (str msg "\r"))
      (.flush)))


  (defn conn-handler [conn server]
    (while (nil? (:exit @conn))
      (let [msg (.readLine (:in @conn))]
        (println msg)
        (cond
          (startswith "ERROR :Closing Link:" msg)
          (dosync (alter conn merge {:exit true}))
          (in " 001 " msg)
          ;; this guy below doesn't seem to work at all
          (map #(write conn (str "JOIN " %)) (:channels server))
          ;; this guy on the other hand seems to work fine
          ;;(write conn (str "JOIN " (first (:channels server))))
          (startswith "PING" msg)
          (write conn (str "PONG " (re-find #":.*" msg)))))))


  (defn login [conn user]
    (write conn (str "NICK " (:nick user)))
    (write conn (str "USER " (:nick user) " 0 * :" (:realname user))))
```

To run this you could simply call: (def irc (connect server)) and then (login irc client). Any help is most appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` is a lazy operation i.e it is not executed until required. When called from repl the repl cause it to evaluate as it needs the returned values to be printed.

You can use `doall` to force the execution of lazy operation.

```
(doall (map ... ))
```

Even better would be to use `doseq` rather than `map`. `map` is for transforming a set of values to another set of values and `doseq` is to perform a operation on a set of values and that what you want to do.

```
(doseq [ch (:channels server)]
  (write conn (str "JOIN " ch)))
```

Comment: `(doall (map ...))` is occasionally easier to write, but I get your point.

Comment: Ah of course! I should have realized what was going on here given that map is lazy but I guess I mentally deferred to the behavior of the REPL without considering that it would force evaluation. Thank you for indulging me.